# sql update temp table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp

1)#tblTemp

```
RD
------
20 Aug
 5 Aug
30 Aug
 4 Aug
20 Aug
18 Aug
```

2) tblMST

```
startDate
---------
22 Aug
 6 Aug
30 Aug
19 Aug
```

I want update table `#tblTemp` using `tblMST` and need to get output like following:

3) #tblTemp

```
RD
--------
22 Aug
 6 Aug
30 Aug
 6 Aug
22 Aug
19 Aug
```

Comment: Please add more detail. it doesn't make any sense right now.

Comment: if 20 Aug not exists in tblMST then  20 Aug replace by 22 Aug v.v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting the nearest date from the tblMST? If so, you want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE #tblTemp SET RD = (SELECT top(1) startDate FROM tblMST WHERE startDate >= RD ORDER BY startDate)
```

Again, I'm not sure if this is the logic you are looking for. Let me know if it is not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a script like below.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.RD = (SELECT MIN(StartDate) FROM tblMST 
 WHERE StartDate >=t.RD)
FROM #tblTemp t
```